# Changing all values of a form that are "on" to "Yes"

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form with lots of check boxes in it that when you check the checkbox the from sends through the value "on". Before I insert them into my database I want to change these to something more usable like the value "Yes" and then for all the boxes that weren't checked the value is "No". Can someone help me with that?

This is my code:

```
<?php

include_once 'database_login.php'; 

$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$fair_trade = $_POST['fair_trade'];
$palm_oil = $_POST['palm_oil'];
$organic = $_POST['organic'];
$gm_free = $_POST['gm_free'];
$nz = $_POST['nz'];
$animals = $_POST['animals'];
$recyclable = $_POST['recyclable'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$sub_category = $_POST['sub_category'];


$add = "INSERT INTO products (barcode, name, company, fair_trade, palm_oil, organic,   gm_free, nz, animals, recyclable, category, sub_category) VALUES ('$barcode', '$name', '$company', '$fair_trade', '$palm_oil', '$organic', '$gm_free', '$nz', '$animals', '$recyclable', '$category', '$sub_category')";
$added = mysqli_query($con, $add);
header( "Location: add.php?message=1");


 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: You're injecting lots and lots of variables directly into your SQL query meaning **SQL injection is super simple**. Switching from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not magically fix this. You need to use prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: the input type checkbox has attribute named `value="yourvalue"` assign that value and get it thru post on form submission page

Comment: Why not just store it as a boolean, then if you need to show the values you can change it after you've retrieved it from the database.

Comment: Will have a look at that h2ooooooo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change values of your checkboxes,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk_name1" value="Yes">
```

as for checkboxes which are not checked but should have `No` value,

```
// all form checkbox
$checkbox = array("chk_name1", "chk_name2");
foreach ($checkbox as $name) $_POST[$name] ?: "No";
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That seems simple enough!

Answer (score 0):

Use shorthand/ternary operators to achieve this.

```
$gm_free = ($_POST['gm_free'] == "on" ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkbox = $_POST['myCheckbox'] == "on" ? "yes" : "no";
```